# How can I compare types in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, typeof, typeid

is there a way to compare types of variables in C++? For example, I want something that works like this: (using pseudolanguage)

```
template <class T> void checkType(T variable) {
    if(type_of(T) == int) cout << "The variable is of type int.\n";
}
```

EDIT 1: I tried to use is_same, but it didn't work in Xcode...but when I try to use it in the following simple code in Atom using Script package it runs.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> void print(T value) {
  if(is_same<T, char> :: value) cout << "char\n";
  if(is_same<T, int> :: value) cout << "int\n";
  if(is_same<T, string> :: value) cout << "string\n";
}

int main() {
  string var1;
  int var2;
  char var3;

  print(var1);
  print(var2);
  print(var3);

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2: I place here the code that doesn't work. Now I tried to comment the part regarding strings and the code works for int and char.

```
template <class keytype, class attrtype>
void LinkedList <keytype, attrtype> :: insert(keytype k, attrtype a) {
    LinkedList <keytype, attrtype> :: position iter = l.head();
    
    if(is_same<keytype, int> :: value) {
        while(iter != NULL and k > iter -> key) {
            iter = l.next(iter);
        }
        
        l.insert(iter, k, a);
    }
    
    else if(is_same<keytype, char> :: value) {
        while(iter != NULL and tolower(k) > tolower(iter -> key)) {
            iter = l.next(iter);
        }
        
        l.insert(iter, k, a);
    }
     //Whatever type I pass by the template in 'keytype' enters this if statement
    else if(is_same<keytype, string> :: value) {
        bool node_filled = false;
        
        if(iter == NULL) {
            l.insert(iter, k, a);
            node_filled = true;
        }
        else {
            unsigned long rif = 0;
            int i = 0;
            
            while(!node_filled and iter != NULL) {
                if(tolower(iter -> key.at(0)) > tolower(k.at(0))) {
                    l.insert(iter, k, a);
                    node_filled = true;
                }
                else if(tolower(iter -> key.at(0)) < tolower(k.at(0))) {
                    iter = l.next(iter);
                }
                else if(tolower(iter -> key.at(0)) == tolower(k.at(0))) {
                    if(k.size() > iter -> key.size())
                        rif = iter -> key.size();
                    else
                        rif = k.size();
                    
                    while((i < rif - 1) and (k.at(i) == iter -> key.at(i))) {
                        i ++;
                    }
                    
                    if(tolower(iter -> key.at(i)) > tolower(k.at(i))) {
                        l.insert(iter, k, a);
                        node_filled = true;
                    }
                    
                    else if(tolower(iter -> key.at(i)) == tolower(k.at(i))) {
                        if(k.size() < iter -> key.size()) {
                            l.insert(iter, k, a);
                            node_filled = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            iter = l.next(iter);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    else if(tolower(iter -> key.at(i)) < tolower(k.at(i))) {
                        iter = l.next(iter);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if(!node_filled) {
                l.insert(NULL, k, a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::is_same<T, int>::value`?

Comment: Algirdas is right, and further - if you want to do something in the `if` statement that would only compile for the specific type tested for, you can do something like `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>) std::cout << "I can can add 2 to " << variable << " to get " << variable + 2 << std::endl;` - that won't get a compiler error if `T` is say `std::string`.  (The `is_same_v` helper saves you having to append `::value`).

Comment: `std::is_same<T, int>::value` would give a nice Boolean value for this exact question, but it's not particularly common to do in practice, because there are so many other things that do type comparison together with something else, and choosing the right tool requires context and a view of the broader problem. So… *what is it you're really solving*?

Comment: I have a LinkedList class made by myself and I want to make a sorting algorithm based on the type of List passed through the template.

Comment: You forgot to include the header that defines `std::is_same`

Comment: eerorika, it gives me the same error...

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: the error is that even if I check whether the type passed is string, int or char, it always goes for string and obviously the program doesn't work properly.

- Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code in EDIT 2, you may want to use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) there instead (assuming a C++17-compliant compiler). The issue here is that normally the compiler will need to syntax check your code for all branches of the if statement, even if logically only one branch could possibly be taken for a given template instantiation.

`if constexpr` relaxes this requirement: the untaken branch is "discarded", which means that values depending on the template arguments are not instantiated if the branch is not taken. This means that it will never try to do, for example, `k.at(0)` when `keytype` is an `int`, since we will not enter that branch if that is the case.

Assuming your compiler supports C++17 (and that standard is enabled!), replacing all the `if` with `if constexpr` in your code should fix this particular issue.

Comment: How can I enable it? It returns me the warning: Constexpr is a C++17 extension.

Comment: @K0sm You mention you are using XCode; I am not familiar with the IDE, but assuming Clang as the compiler you should work out how to pass `-std=c++17` to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

This work for me.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void print(T value) {
  if (is_same<T, char>::value) cout << "char\n";
  if (is_same<T, int>::value) cout << "int\n";
  if (is_same<T, string>::value) cout << "string\n";
}

int main() {
  string var1;
  int var2;
  char var3;

  print(var1);
  print(var2);
  print(var3);

  return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/JxjDC4)

In C++17, you can use `if constexpr` to let the compiler generate more optimal codegen:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
void print(T value) {
  if constexpr (is_same_v<T, char>) cout << "char\n";
  if constexpr (is_same_v<T, int>) cout << "int\n";
  if constexpr (is_same_v<T, string>) cout << "string\n";
}

int main() {
  string var1;
  int var2;
  char var3;

  print(var1);
  print(var2);
  print(var3);

  return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/By6IM0-5P)

Comment: I already tried this in Atom and, as the post says, it worked. The problem is that it doesn't work in Xcode.

Comment: Then you are going to have to be more specific about WHAT doesn't work exactly

Comment: The errors given are: - Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union and - Member reference base type 'char' is not a structure or union

Answer (score 0):

In C++ there is the `typeid()` operator which returns a `std::type_info`, this can be used in a couple of ways.

You use `std::type_info::hash_code()` like this:

```
template<typename T>
void print()
{
    if (typeid(T).hash_code() == typeid(char).hash_code())
        std::cout << "char\n"
    else if (typeid(T).hash_code() == typeid(int).hash_code())
        std::cout << "int\n"
    else if (typeid(T).hash_code() == typeid(std::string).hash_code())
        std::cout << "std::string\n"
}
```

or, you could use `std::type_info::name()` like this:

```
template<typename T>
void print()
{
    std::cout << typeid(T) << '\n';
}
```

Just beware with the latter that if you put something like `std::string`, you will end up with something like `class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >` for an output. That's just because `std::string` is a `using` define for `class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >`.

Edit: I forgot to say, you need a `#include <typeinfo>` to use `std::type_info`.

Answer (score -4):

You can try this:

```
template <class T> void checkType(T variable) {
    switch(sizeof(T)){
    case sizeof(int) :
        cout << "The variable is of type int.\n";
        break;
    case sizeof(char):
        cout << "The variable is of type char.\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

Observation: if you have a vector you will have to give it a special treatment by dividing it sizeof int the switch parameter by the number of allocations of the vector for example.

Comment: This won't work even for built-in types. When `struct`s and `class`es come into play, this will work even less. `sizeof` is not unique per type.

Comment: Sizeof does return de lenth of the variable in bytes. So if you type in a sizeof(char variable) it will return 1 byte for any char variable not depending on its content. And with vectors it will return its type size times its number of allocations. The same for other types.

Comment: Given `std::vector<int> little = {1, 2, 3}; std::vector<int> large = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};`, `sizeof(little) == sizeof(large)`, so you are mistaken here. Another example: `struct foo1{ int x; }; struct foo2 { short s1; short s2; };`. Assuming that `short` is 2 bytes and `int` is 4 bytes, `sizeof(foo1) == sizeof(foo2)`. But `foo1` and `foo2` are very different types. You solution does not work.

Comment: `sizeof(bool) == sizeof(char)` so you would not be able to differentiate them on size alone.  Same with `(u)int16_t` and `(unsigned) short`, `(u)int32_t` and `(unsigned) int` etc.  Different types, but they can have the same sizes.